# Recreate selected UITabBarItem border

Tags: ios, ios5, core-graphics, core-image

I want to recreate a tab bar but I stumbled on this problem. As you can see in the images below my current (right image) selected tab bar item is a lot less crisp or sharper than the one from the UITabBar. Notice the small 1 point border around the icon in the left (which I don't know how to do) as well as the gradient inside the icon which is a lot noticeable in mine. I already thought of Core Graphics and Core Images Filters as possible approaches but can't seem to get that effect. I found an older [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052549/simulating-selected-tab-bar-effect) which is part of what I want but the answer doesn't seem to work for me and requires a manual loop through the pixels of the image (which I don't know if it is to be desired). Can someone help me?

[image: desired]
[image: current]

This is the code I'm currently using which, btw, you're welcome to correct some mistakes if you see any because I'm starting with Core Graphics:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    {
        /* Adjust for different coordinate systems from UIKit and Core Graphics and center the image */
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.bounds.size.width/2.0 - self.image.size.width/2.0, self.bounds.size.height - self.bounds.size.height/2.0 + self.image.size.height/2.0);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height);

        /* Add a drop shadow */
        UIColor *dropShadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.8f];
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 1), 5, dropShadowColor.CGColor);

        /* Draw the original image */
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.image.CGImage);

        /* Clip to the original image, so that we only draw the shadows on the
           inside of the image but nothing outside. */
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.image.CGImage);

        if(self.isSelected){
            /* draw background image */
            CGImageRef background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UITabBarBlueGradient"].CGImage;
            CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, background);
        }
        else{
            /* draw background color to unselected items */
            CGColorRef backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:95/255.0 green:95/255.0 blue:95/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, backgroundColor);
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

            /* location of the gradient's colors */
            CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

            NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.6].CGColor, nil];

            /* create the gradient with colors and locations */
            CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,(__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);
            {
                /* start and end points of the gradient */
                CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
                CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
                /* draw gradient */
                CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
            }
            CGGradientRelease(gradient);
        }
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on this too, an optimization you can probably make is instead of rendering the UIImage each time drawrect is called you can save off the UIImage objects in an ivar and just update a UIImageView.image property to display them.

I'm generating my image with the "shine" like this:

(plus_icon.png is a 30 x 30 image with a 4 px wide cross occupying the entire thing in black on a transparent background:  [image: plus icon] which renders like in imageView 2 and 4 like this: [image: rendered plus icon]

```
-(UIImage *)tabBarImage{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(60, 60));

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_icon"];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60));

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(15, 15, 30, 30);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect, [image CGImage]);

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

-(UIImage *)sourceImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(60.0, 60.0));

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.3, 1.0 };

    CGFloat components[8] = {NC(72), NC(122), NC(229), 1.0, NC(110), NC(202), NC(255), 1.0 };

    CGColorSpaceRef cspace;
    CGGradientRef gradient;
    cspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (cspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGPoint sPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 15.0);
    CGPoint ePoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 45.0);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient (context, gradient, sPoint, ePoint, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation| kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(cspace);
    [self addShineToContext:context];

    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return image;
}

-(void)addShineToContext:(CGContextRef) context{
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.3, 0.7};
    CGFloat components[8] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};//{0.82, 0.82, 0.82, 0.4,  0.92, 0.92, 0.92, .8 };

    CGColorSpaceRef cspace;
    CGGradientRef gradient;
    cspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (cspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGPoint sPoint = CGPointMake(25.0f, 15.0);
    CGPoint ePoint = CGPointMake(35.0f, 44.0f);


    [self addShineClip:context];

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, sPoint, ePoint, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);
//    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
//    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(15,15, 30, 30));

    CGColorSpaceRelease(cspace);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}

-(void)addShineClip:(CGContextRef)context{
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 15, 35);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, 25, 30, 45, 28);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 45, 15);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 15, 15);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.imageView1.image = [self compositeOverSlate:[self drawTabBarOverSourceWithBlend:kCGBlendModeSourceIn]];
    self.imageView2.image = [self compositeOverSlate:[self drawTabBarOverSourceWithBlend:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn]];
    self.imageView3.image = [self compositeOverSlate:[self drawTabBarOverSourceWithBlend:kCGBlendModeSourceAtop]];
    self.imageView4.image = [self compositeOverSlate:[self drawTabBarOverSourceWithBlend:kCGBlendModeDestinationAtop]];
}

-(UIImage *)compositeOverSlate:(UIImage *)image{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    imageRect.size = image.size;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]);

    CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);
    CGContextSetShadow(ctx, CGSizeMake(-1.0, 2.0), .5);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect, [image CGImage]);

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}

-(UIImage *)drawTabBarOverSourceWithBlend:(CGBlendMode)blendMode{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(60,60));
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0, 60.0), [[self sourceImage] CGImage]);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, blendMode);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0, 60.0), [[self tabBarImage] CGImage]);

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

but I don't have the border outline cracked yet, but will update if I do crack it.